# firebird performance on tpch query

Tags: query-optimization, firebird, benchmarking

I am working on tpch benchmark which has a set of 22 queries. in query number 15 there is a view involved, after creating the view when i go to run query everything just freezes no result can anyone help me in this. by the way on Postgres same query comes back in 3.68 seconds.View and query is below

```
   create view revenue0 (supplier_no, total_revenue) as
select
    l_suppkey,
    sum(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount))
from
    lineitem
where
    l_shipdate >= date '1997-05-01'
    and l_shipdate < dateadd(month, 3, date '1997-05-01')
group by
    l_suppkey;
```

query

```
select
s_suppkey,
s_name,
s_address,
s_phone,
total_revenue
    from
supplier,
revenue0
    where
s_suppkey = supplier_no
and total_revenue = (
    select
        max(total_revenue)
    from
        revenue0
        )
    order by
s_suppkey;
```

Comment: prepare the query (do not run it yet, just prepare) and report the query plan

Comment: try asking guys who did it before - http://firebird.1100200.n4.nabble.com/TPC-benchmark-suite-td2241151.html

Comment: I think you need to provide more information. What Firebird version, did you commit the create view statement before executing the select? What is the exact DDL used? The query itself is also a bit odd with its SQL-89 style joins and the uncorrelated sub-query that might get re-executed for each row, but I don't see why it should hang, except if you have inserted data in another transaction and haven't committed that transaction, and you are selecting using table stability isolation or read committed with no_recversion.